# Selenium+Python. How to locate several elements within a specific element?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Python+Selenium to scrape data from a site which lists companies' info.

For each company I need 2 data points - email and url.

The problem is - for some companies email is not indicated and if I separately get a list of urls and emails I won't be able to fit the pairs (list of emails will be shorter than list of url and I won't know which of the emails is missing).

So I thought maybe there is a way to get root elements of each of the companies' blocks (say, it is div with class "provider") and then search inside each of them for email and url.

Is it possible and if yes - how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you please share the html of the sample div element (with email and url) so that we can provide the solution.

Comment: @supputuri thank you! Here's the url I'm working with: https://clutch.co/web-designers?page=0

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can do it.

**First**: Simply use the selector to find the element in children of that 'div' element. You can use find_elements functions to check how many parent 'divs' are there first, and then loop that many times. This method is not recommended.

**Second**: You can call find_element family of functions on a webelement object.

Assume that I am working on [this](https://www.webscraper.io/test-sites) website.

```
### First method:
FirstTitleInDiv = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".row.test-site:nth-of-type(1) h2") # get first title
SecondTitleInDiv = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".row.test-site:nth-of-type(2) h2") # get second title
# ... and so on.

### Second method:
Div_Els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".row.test-site") # get list of all divs
# You can now loop through all divs in order to do following:
FirstTitleInDiv = Div_Els[0].find_element_by_css_selector("h2") # get first title
SecondTitleInDiv = Div_Els[1].find_element_by_css_selector("h2") # get second title
# ... and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you, @zaif

I tried this approach with the code:

<code>
providers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('provider-row')
for provider in providers:
    companyEmail = provider.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='item']/a")
    emailNum = 0
    for email in companyEmail:
        print(emailNum, email.get_attribute("href"))
        emailNum += 1
</code>

But the inner code doesn't look to be searching within current "provider-row" div, rather - it takes all elements from the page which meet the xpath requirement "//div[@class='item']/a".

Comment: @TonySimonovsky I believe the issue is with the xpath of inner code. Start xpath with **//** searches the elements in the whole document. Perhaps **.//** will work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the complete logic.

```
url = "https://clutch.co/web-designers?page=0"
driver.get(url)
pros = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.provider-row")
providers =[]
for provider in pros:

    pUrl = provider.find_element_by_css_selector(".website-link.website-link-a a").get_attribute("realurl")
    if (len(provider.find_elements_by_css_selector(".contact-dropdown .item a"))>0):
        pEmail = provider.find_element_by_css_selector(".contact-dropdown .item a").get_attribute('textContent')
    else:
        pEmail=''
    providers.append("{" + pUrl + "," +  pEmail + "}")
print(providers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution.

First you collect all the blocks with fields you need to get. Example:

`providers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('provider-row')`

And then you use find_elements_by_xpath() method with locator starting with ".//" which means search inside a specific element. Example:

`providers[0].find_elements_by_xpath(".//li[@class='website-link website-link-a']/a[@class='sl-ext']")`